# Undefined reference in c... What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, linux, g++

I have the following code... which is throwing a `main.cpp:18: undefined reference to phrase_init()` Coming from `C#` experience C is a bit annoying especially when trying to figure out where the problem is :( Any idea or pointer will be greatly appreciated!

## phrase.h:

```
#ifndef PHRASE_H
#define PHRASE_H

typedef struct
{
    char* Word1;
    char* Word2;
} Phrase;

Phrase* phrase_init(void);

#endif
```

## Phrase.c :

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "phrase.h"

Phrase* phrase_init()
{
    Phrase* phrase = (Phrase *)malloc(sizeof(Phrase));

    phrase->Word1 = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
    phrase->Word2 = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));

    return phrase;
}
```

## main.c

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cctype>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "phrase.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    char* word1 = "Testing";
    char* word2 = "Word2";

    Phrase* test = phrase_init();
    strcpy(test->Word1, word1);
    strcpy(test->Word2, word2);

    printf("Word 1: %s", test->Word1);
    printf("Word 2: %s", test->Word2);

    scanf("%s", word1);

}
```

## Makefile:

```
#
#  There exist several targets which are by default empty and which can be 
#  used for execution of your targets. These targets are usually executed 
#  before and after some main targets. They are: 
#
#     .build-pre:              called before 'build' target
#     .build-post:             called after 'build' target
#     .clean-pre:              called before 'clean' target
#     .clean-post:             called after 'clean' target
#     .clobber-pre:            called before 'clobber' target
#     .clobber-post:           called after 'clobber' target
#     .all-pre:                called before 'all' target
#     .all-post:               called after 'all' target
#     .help-pre:               called before 'help' target
#     .help-post:              called after 'help' target
#
#  Targets beginning with '.' are not intended to be called on their own.
#
#  Main targets can be executed directly, and they are:
#  
#     build                    build a specific configuration
#     clean                    remove built files from a configuration
#     clobber                  remove all built files
#     all                      build all configurations
#     help                     print help mesage
#  
#  Targets .build-impl, .clean-impl, .clobber-impl, .all-impl, and
#  .help-impl are implemented in nbproject/makefile-impl.mk.
#
#  Available make variables:
#
#     CND_BASEDIR                base directory for relative paths
#     CND_DISTDIR                default top distribution directory (build artifacts)
#     CND_BUILDDIR               default top build directory (object files, ...)
#     CONF                       name of current configuration
#     CND_PLATFORM_${CONF}       platform name (current configuration)
#     CND_ARTIFACT_DIR_${CONF}   directory of build artifact (current configuration)
#     CND_ARTIFACT_NAME_${CONF}  name of build artifact (current configuration)
#     CND_ARTIFACT_PATH_${CONF}  path to build artifact (current configuration)
#     CND_PACKAGE_DIR_${CONF}    directory of package (current configuration)
#     CND_PACKAGE_NAME_${CONF}   name of package (current configuration)
#     CND_PACKAGE_PATH_${CONF}   path to package (current configuration)
#
# NOCDDL


# Environment 
MKDIR=mkdir
CP=cp
CCADMIN=CCadmin


# build
build: .build-post

.build-pre:
# Add your pre 'build' code here...

.build-post: .build-impl
# Add your post 'build' code here...


# clean
clean: .clean-post

.clean-pre:
# Add your pre 'clean' code here...

.clean-post: .clean-impl
# Add your post 'clean' code here...


# clobber
clobber: .clobber-post

.clobber-pre:
# Add your pre 'clobber' code here...

.clobber-post: .clobber-impl
# Add your post 'clobber' code here...


# all
all: .all-post

.all-pre:
# Add your pre 'all' code here...

.all-post: .all-impl
# Add your post 'all' code here...


# build tests
build-tests: .build-tests-post

.build-tests-pre:
# Add your pre 'build-tests' code here...

.build-tests-post: .build-tests-impl
# Add your post 'build-tests' code here...


# run tests
test: .test-post

.test-pre:
# Add your pre 'test' code here...

.test-post: .test-impl
# Add your post 'test' code here...


# help
help: .help-post

.help-pre:
# Add your pre 'help' code here...

.help-post: .help-impl
# Add your post 'help' code here...



# include project implementation makefile
include nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk

# include project make variables
include nbproject/Makefile-variables.mk
```

Comment: Need a few pointers? (Sorry, couldn't help myself) http://xkcd.com/138/

Comment: There's a good chance you're compiling/linking it wrong, show us the command you use to compile/link the program.

Comment: Can you paste your compile and link script?

Comment: Uhm... don't know. I am using NetBeans C++ 7. Like I said... c# background with VS2010 as tool of choice. Not familiar with Linux VI, making makefiles... etc. (Yet)

Comment: Also, is there a reason why you're writing code in a C way (ie. `typedef`ing the struct, which is unnecessary in C++), but including C++ headers? Not to mention why you include both `<stdlib.h>` and `<cstdlib>`.

Comment: Like the other commenters have said, it's probably the way you're compiling.  It sounds like you're trying to compile main.c without Phrase.c

Comment: I think you're looking for http://debug-my-code-for-me.com

Comment: Also, why are you using `.c` as a c++ extension?

Comment: Yes, I realize that <*.h> is the C way and that I have C extensions. But like I said in the later post - I accidentally made my project to be a C++ project which makes the AutoComplete automatically browser to CPP project header files. I rebuilt the project with settings for C and it all worked fine (minus the c++ includes, and corrected file extensions...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to tell the linker where to find the symbol.

For example:

```
g++ -c phrase.cpp            # creates phrase.o which defines phrase_init()
g++ -c main.cpp              # creates main.o which refers to phrase_init()
g++ phrase.o main.o -o main  # creates executable file "main"
```

Or, to do all of the above in one command:

```
g++ phrase.cpp main.cpp -o main
```

Note that I'm assuming both source files are C++, and are named with `.cpp` extensions.  Your question refers to files with both `.c` and `.cpp` extensions, and the question is tagged [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

If you're using C, then you shouldn't be using C++-specific headers in `main.c`, and you should use `gcc` rather than `g++`.

If you're using C++, all your source files should have `.cpp` suffixes and you should used `g++`.

And if you're trying to mix C and C++, then [you should be using `extern "C"`](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html) so the compiler knows what you're doing (but it's usually easier to use pure C++).

Comment: Ok, thanks! I just realized that it is the type of project in NetBeans that is making all the mashup. By default it creates a main.cpp, and is thinking the code is in c++.

Comment: @bleepzter: It is C++; there's no `<iostream>` in C.

Answer (score 1):

And you really should compile with `-Wall -g` so add to your `Makefile`

```
CXXFLAGS+= -Wall -g
CFLAGS+= -Wall -g
```

the first is for C++, the second is for C

I also think you should write by hand your own (simpler) `Makefile` for [make](http://www.gnu.org/s/make/)  (instead of copying a more complex `Makefile` that you don't understand).